# Docker Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot)

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have this domain: dev-core.app.example.com that I am trying to install an ssl certificate for using this tutorial: https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71

However, when it comes to requesting a certificate from letsencrypt, I get this error:

> Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot).
> The Certificate Authority reported these problems:   Domain:
> dev-core-app.example.com   Type:   unauthorized   Detail:
> 100.100.100.100: Invalid response from http://dev-core-app.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/XyWgWZVTZgMzvYjFCYVVypLNeDhgE1lNFVN2U0eaubk:
> 404
>
> Domain: [www.dev-core-app.example.com](http://www.dev-core-app.example.com)   Type:   unauthorized
> Detail: 100.100.100.100: Invalid response from
> http://www.dev-core-app.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/OnGprMCbHeQRdas5cST7bsYNpa762PwaDLLrsU2H7Bg:
> 404

I have tried searching in the folder and no files appear in it.

This is my nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name dev-core-app.example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    error_log /var/log/nginx/sdr-fe-nginx-error.log info;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sdr-fe-nginx-access.log;

    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    # Allow larger than normal headers
    large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
    proxy_buffers         8 16k;  # Buffer pool = 8 buffers of 16k
    proxy_buffer_size     16k;    # 16k of buffers from pool used for headers
    

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        rewrite ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge(.*) $1 break;
        root /var/www/certbot;
    } 
    location /{
        proxy_pass http://gateway_us/;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

This is my docker-compose file showing my nginx and certbot configuration:

```
nginx:
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Singapore
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks: 
    - ${NETWORK}
    volumes:
      - ./fe_nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
```

I have tested placing a file in .well-known/acme-challenge/ and have managed to access it via the url dev-core-app.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt

What else am I missing in my configuration?
I use the init-letsencrypt.sh file provided by the site.